# jQuery - Equal Div-Heights after Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to set all my divs to the height of the highest div on load and on resize. Here's the code:

```
// set equal column heights
function eqColumn(){
    if ($(window).width() > 767){
        var item = $(".item");
        var biggest = 0;
        $(item).each(function(){
            if ($(this).height() > biggest){
                biggest = $(this).height();
                console.log(".item height = " + biggest);
            }
        });
        item.css("height", biggest);
    }
}

// bind events
$(window).on("load resize", eqColumn);
```

It works fine on load, but not when I resize the window. When I log the value in the console, the value doesn't change on resize. I'm really stumped. Here's the example site: http://dev.thomasveit.com/zuzuegler/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I did not know you could set multiple events like that ("load resize"). I always used multiple lines ...

Comment: could it be the size you are resizing it to is below your width restraint?

Comment: Why do you expect the height to change on resize ? You have already fixed it on load with `css("height" ...`

Comment: I don't understand: Why the 3 up-votes? And @singe31 seems to have the same feel i think.

Comment: The functions will be executed on resize and the var biggest should be reseted. so it should calculate the highest div again on every resize.

Comment: No it doesn"t work like that, you have fixed the height for all the div in the load event. So, when you calculate `$(this).height()` on resize it will give you the same value for everry div (the `biggest` calculated is the load event) You don't reset the height by doing `var biggest = 0;`

Comment: @singe31 yeah thank you, you're absolutely right... i really feel stupid now :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is because all items are equally big after load/resize. Because you resize them all when the eqColumn function runs for the first time:

```
item.css("height", biggest);
```

Try resetting the .item size before the .each iteration:

```
function eqColumn(){
if ($(window).width() > 767){
    var item = $(".item");
    //reset the height to auto
    item.css("height", "auto");
    var biggest = 0;
    $(item).each(function(){
        if ($(this).height() > biggest){
            biggest = $(this).height();
            console.log(".item height = " + biggest);
        }
    });
    item.css("height", biggest);
}
}
```